# How can I print statement all at once in the end in java

Tags: java

my code need to input multiple of student id and score for midterm and final to find sum and tell what grade they will have and need to print all the result at the end

> This is my code

```
class Score{
private int mid, fin,sum;
private String grade, id;
public void data(int i){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input_id = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter data for student"+ " #"+ i+"\r\n");
    System.out.print("Enter student ID: ");
    id = input_id.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter midterm and final scores: ");
    mid = input.nextInt();
    fin = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
}

public void calScore(){
    sum = mid+fin;
    if (sum < 45)
        grade = "F";
    else if (sum >= 45 && sum <= 50)
        grade = "D";
    else if (sum >= 51 && sum <= 55)
        grade = "D+";
    else if (sum >= 56 && sum <= 60)
        grade = "C";
    else if (sum >= 61 && sum <= 65)
        grade = "C+";
    else if (sum >= 66 && sum <= 70)
        grade = "B";
    else if (sum >= 71 && sum <= 85)
        grade = "B+";
    else
        grade = "A";            
}

public void Result(int i){
    System.out.print(i + id +"  "+ sum + "  "+grade+"\n");
}
public class tellgrade {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i,n;
    System.out.print("Enter N: ");
    n = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print(" ");
    
    Score[] sc = new Score[n];
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        sc[i] = new Score();
        sc[i].data(i+1);
        sc[i].calScore();
        sc[i].Result(i+1);
    }
}
```

}

this is result I have

```
Enter N: 2

Enter data for student #1
Enter student ID: 611401111
Enter midterm and final scores: 20 30

1  611401111  50  D

Enter data for student #2
Enter student ID: 611401222
Enter midterm and final scores: 20 50

2  611401222  70  B
```

But expected result is

```
Enter N: 2

Enter data for student #1
Enter student ID: 611401111
Enter midterm and final scores: 20 30

Enter data for student #2
Enter student ID: 611401222
Enter midterm and final scores: 20 50


1  611401111  50  D
2  611401222  70  B
```

and have try everytihng i know but it's didn't work SO plase help me out. Thank you (sorry for bad english)

Comment: Are you allowed to use arrays for this assignment?  I find that sometimes the instructor specific does not want students to use an array which of course will also work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `.Result()` in the same loop:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    sc[i] = new Score();
    sc[i].data(i+1);
    sc[i].calScore();
    sc[i].Result(i+1);
}
```

If what you want instead is to re-start from the beginning and call `.Result()` in a new loop, then what you want is two loops:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    sc[i] = new Score();
    sc[i].data(i+1);
    sc[i].calScore();
}

for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    sc[i].Result(i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the `Result` method in the second loop

```java
    Score[] sc = new Score[n];
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        sc[i] = new Score();
        sc[i].data(i+1);
        sc[i].calScore();
    }

    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        sc[i].Result(i+1);
    }
```

In the first loop you will read and compute all data, and in the second one you will only print the `System.out.println`